# Make Absolute position div always visible from top to bottom

Tags: css

For my site, I need an area to sit along the edge of the viewport to reveal a menu when dragged.  The div that defines that area cannot be `position:fixed`, and I am trying to accomplish this without javascript.
Here's my basic html:

```
    <div id="content" class="snap-content">
        <div id="toolbar">
            <a href="#" id="open-left"></a>
            <h1>Default</h1>
        </div>
               // Content
        <div id="do-drag"></div>
    </div>
```

That `#do-drag` div I need to sit along the left edge of the viewport, running top to bottom, about 25px wide, regardless of how much content there is.  It cannot be `position:fixed`.  It needs to always be there.  And the drag div must sit inside the `content` div.

Now, I see two possibilities:

- A 100% tall `absolute` div that doesn't actually scroll, or...
- A div that scrolls, but that is never shorter than 100% of the viewport

I have tried placing the `#do-drag` inside of another div and mixing up absolute and relative positioning.  I have tried extending the drag div to 800% and using `overflow` settings to clip it.  These, and a couple other attempts, have failed.

Comment: No position fixed + no JavaScript = not gonna happen.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you can't used fixed positioning, but the only other way is to redefine your viewport by creating an element that constitutes your viewport.

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow-y:scroll;` to content? Without javascript it is rather difficult...

Comment: @j08691, I'd make a concession for javascript as long as it was vanilla JS and wasn't visually jerky.

Comment: @David this is what I'm talking about with redefining the container: http://jsfiddle.net/p7n4mz4w/

Comment: @Chad, I see, but you placed the content inside the drag div.  It belongs above the drag div, and there should be no content in the drag div.

Comment: @ShaunLoftin, `overflow:scroll` does not seem to work, regardless of how I define the drag div.

Comment: @David then probably not possible. The point is that the overflow should be on an item that doesn't contain the menu.

Comment: Well nothing is going to scroll if the height is 100%, the height would have to be more. The purpose of scrolling is to see what doesn't fit in the view of the div.

Comment: @Chad, I came up with this by switching things around in your fiddle.  It seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/p7n4mz4w/1/

Comment: @David Yea, same theory. Just don't allow the parent of the non-scrolling element to have scrolling and you can use abs pos.